# Sorting two columns in c# using the values in one column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two columns

```
form.myDataTable.Rows[i][2 * cs] = corr;                
form.myDataTable.Rows[i][2 * cs + 1] = "p" + Convert.ToString(col1) + " p" + Convert.ToString(col2);
```

I need to sort `2*cs` column by values and also corresponding names in column `2*cs+1`.

I am trying like this:
var corrvalues = new Dictionary();
correlationvalues["p" + Convert.ToString(col1) + " p" + Convert.ToString(col2)] = corr;
sortedvalues = correlationvalues.Values.OrderByDescending;

I am not clear how to use orderbydescending, i am new to c#. Thanks for help.

Comment: You want to sort column? Usually rows are sorted...

Comment: I need to sort the numbers highest to lowest in one column and corresponding names in another column

Answer (score 0):

it is much easier, if you are using databinding.

you can fill the datagrid by

```
form.myDataTable.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(i => new { Column1 = corr, Column2 = "p" + Convert.ToString(col1) + " p" + Convert.ToString(col2) }).ToArray();
```

doing a sort is then also easier

```
form.myDataTable.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(i => new { Column1 = corr, Column2 = "p" + Convert.ToString(col1) + " p" + Convert.ToString(col2) }).OrderBy(k => k.Column2).ToArray();
```

Comment: I am trying your code now. I am new to c#. Can you pleas explain how can i use databinding.

Comment: this will not be data bound. For that you need to use collectionviewsource

Comment: Hi Tilak, sortedvalues = correlationvalues.Values.OrderByDescending, how to use orderbydescending?i am not clear about it